# Is there a way to determine if a method has been overridden in a Java class

Tags: java, oop, overriding

I want to be able to determine if a base class method has been overridden by a subclass specifically because expensive setup is needed before invoking it and most subclasses in our system do not override it. Can it be tested by using reflection provided method handles? Or is there some other way to test if a class method is overridden?

e.g.

```
class BaseClass {
    void aMethod() { // don nothing }

    protected boolean aMethodHasBeenOverridden() {
        return( // determine if aMethod has been overridden by a subclass);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do it with reflection by examining the declaring class of your method:

```
class Base {
    public void foo() {}
    public void bar() {}
}
class Derived extends Base {
    @Override   
    public void bar() {}
}
...
Method mfoo = Derived.class.getMethod("foo");
boolean ovrFoo = mfoo.getDeclaringClass() != Base.class;
Method mbar = Derived.class.getMethod("bar");
boolean ovrBar = mbar.getDeclaringClass() != Base.class;
System.out.println("Have override for foo: "+ovrFoo);
System.out.println("Have override for bar: "+ovrBar);
```

Prints

```
Have override for foo: false
Have override for bar: true
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/P0s7Nx)

Comment: Problem if the method is overridden on an intermediate class between the base class and the leaf class.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for pointing this out. Comparing the declaring class to `Base.class` solves this problem.

Comment: Minor note - C++ uses the terminology **base class** and **derived class**; Java uses the terminology **superclass** and **subclass**.

Comment: @Nayuki: It's also common, however, to use `class Base` and `class Derived extends Base` in Java examples; `class Super` and `class Sub` are much less common, probably because `super` is a keyword and `Sub` just looks a bit weird.

Comment: @Nayuki Additionally, when talking about hierarchies rather than simply two levels, "base" is often used to indicate the supermost class involved.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done calling `getClass().getDeclaredMethod("aMethod")`, which returns something only if the class of `this` declared it.

Here's an implementation of your method:

```
/**
 * @return true if the instance's class overrode aMethod
 */
protected boolean aMethodHasBeenOverridden() {
    try {
        return getClass() != A.class && getClass().getDeclaredMethod("aMethod") != null;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach I'd take is to only make this method *exist* if the subclass needs it by overriding method that calls it in an abstract intermediate class. Here's what that would look like:

```
public abstract class MovingThing {
    public void move() {
        // walk a few feet
    }
}
```

Now a few of your moving things teleport, but that requires charging the flux capacitors and other expensive things, so separate that out:

```
public abstract class TeleportingThing extends MovingThing {
    @Override
    public void move() {
        fluxCapacitor.charge();
        stardate.calculate();
        doTeleport();
    }

    protected abstract void doTeleport();
}
```

Your classes that need the expensive setup derive from the second class that includes it, while the ones that don't can derive from the first class. This pattern is a sort of Decorator and is used, for example, in the Servlet API, where most servlets override something like `doGet()` and leave the parsing to `service()`.

Comment: The problem with this is that it makes an implementation detail (i.e., how the expensive setup is avoided if not strictly necessary) affect the public API (i.e., the inheritance chain). And worse, it only works for a *single* method (at least in Java), because you can only inherit from a single base class. Simply having a `protected boolean aMethodHasBeenOverridden()` method as in the OP's question might look less elegant at first sight, but would actually be preferrable, since it doesn't have any of these down-sides...

Comment: @fgp Putting that method into the class has exactly the same issue about exposing the public API, and my technique can apply to any set of potentially overridable methods.

Comment: You method couples the choice of base class with whether doTeleport() is overridden, so if you have two such methods and want to override one but not the other, how would you do that?

Comment: @fgp As in Servlet? (Though at this point I'd be into Groovy traits, myself.)

Comment: I don't know how `Servlet` handles things, so, um, maybe... :-) Anyway, lets just agree to disagree on whether your approach is elegant or overly complicated - sometimes that distinction is more a matter of taste than anything else anway...