# Difference between class method and superclass method

Tags: java, reflection

I have code where I find all of the methods of the `B` class.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {

    public static class A {
        public Object e() { return new Object(); }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        @Override
        public String e() { return "hi"; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Method md : B.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + md.getName());
            System.out.println("Declaring class: " + md.getDeclaringClass().getName());
            System.out.println("Return type: " + md.getReturnType().getName());
        }
    }

}
```

This is what the code returns:

```
Name: e
Declaring class: Main$B
Return type: java.lang.String
Name: e
Declaring class: Main$B
Return type: java.lang.Object
```

However, I cannot differentiate between the overrided method and the original one because they have the same declaring class. My question is: Without being given the code of the class, how do I find whether a method is inherited if it has a different return value than the superclass method.

edit:
This is not the same as my previous question as it is about interfaces while this question is about inheritance.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77289913/8681)?

Comment: The 'previous question' is about methods declared in an interface. Other than overridden from superclass, interface methods do not override parent implementations. So it is not entirely the same.

Comment: Here is a similar question and answer.  _https://stackoverflow.com/a/38554828/17758716_.

Comment: @Reilas This is not what I was looking for. This time, the declaring classes are the same for some reason.

Comment: You are overriding `e()` but changed the return type. That results in a synthetic method being generated (it's how covariant return types are implemented).

Comment: @Slaw So how is it possible to see which method was defined in class B, not A? Why are both declaring classes the same when the second one was defined in class A?

Comment: The simplest way to understand this is that there isn't an override, they both exist. If you _absolutely_ need an override, then you should change both return types to `Object` and check if the return type is an `instanceof` String.

Comment: When you call `B.class.getDeclaredMethods()` you only get methods whose `getDeclaringClass()` will return `B.class`. That’s already implied by the name of the method. It’s not clear how you can expect a method declared a `A` when you ask for methods declared in `B`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You're possibly confused about what you're witnessing. Both of those methods are declared in B. You're not seeing the one declared in A! The reason there are 2 is.. some JLS/JVMS interactive weirdness that is unexpected. Possibly you knew that, in which case you can skip the first section.

### Wait, what, 2 methods in B??

Yes, there really are 2 methods in B. There is a difference in how java (the language) works, and java (the virtual machine) works. As a trivial example, inner classes exist in java-the-language and do not exist<sup>1</sup> in java-the-VM. Whenever this happens, javac needs to generate a bunch of extra code to 'fix it'. Usually, these involve something called **synthetic members** - methods (and, rarely, fields and constructors) that are made out of whole cloth by javac to make things work. These methods have the 'synthetic' flag enabled and `javac` acts as if such things do not exist. However, the JVM (`java.exe`) doesn't take the synthetic flag into consideration whatsoever.

javac generates an extra (synthetic) method when compiling B. That happens whenever you 'tighten' the return type of a method you are overriding.

That's because java-the-language considers a method identity to be based on its name and its parameter types. However, java-the-VM is slightly different, in that it considers a method identity to be based on its name and its parameter types **and its return type**. Hence, in java, your `Object e()` from `A` and your `String e()` from `B` are considered the same method (as in, the one in B overrides the one in A), but at the JVM level, they are not.

To fix this conflict, javac generates a method. It compiles your B as if you wrote:

```
public class B extends A {
  @Override
  public String e() { return "hi"; }

  @Synthetic
  public Object e() { return theOtherE(); }
}
```

You can literally see this: `javap -c -v B.class` after compiling it and this synthetic method will show up. With 'this is synthetic' actually in the output of javap.

**That** is the 'second' e() you are seeing in your code. You do not see A's `e()` method because `.getDeclaredMethods()` does not return any inherited methods, at all. `getMethods()` does (but only public ones).

### So how do I get A's `e()` `java.lang.reflect.Method` object?

There *is* a way to get a `Method` instance that represents that method. Including the notion that `md.getDeclaringClass()` would return A.

`.getDeclaredMethods()` only returns methods declared in the class you call it on. `getMethods()` returns all methods a class has - even the ones it inherited - but only public/protected ones. There is no method that gets you all methods (including inherited ones) regardless of access level. We can see this:

```
class Parent {
  public void parentPublicMethod() {}
  private void parentPrivateMethod() {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  public void childPublicMethod() {}
  private void childPrivateMethod() {}
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (Method m : Child.class.getMethods()) {
      System.out.println("getMethods: " + m.getName());
    }
    for (Method m : Child.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
      System.out.println("getDeclaredMethods: " + m.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
getMethods: childPublicMethod
getMethods: parentPublicMethod
getMethods: (every public method in Object, such as toString)
getDeclaredMethods: childPublicMethod
getDeclaredMethods: childPrivateMethod
```

The one and only way you can get `parentPrivateMethod` to print is something like:

```
Class<?> c = Child.class;
while (c != Object.class) {
  for (Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    System.out.println(c.getName() + "::" + m.getName());
  }
  c = c.getSuperclass();
}
```

this will get you:

```
Child::childPublicMethod
Child::childPrivateMethod
Parent::parentPublicMethod
Parent::parentPrivateMethod
```

Note that it is generally a bad idea to write code that tries to draw a distinction between whether a method is overridden or not. The only way to know that is to use reflection. Java programs do not normally care about it, it's bad practice to do so. Whatever reason you're asking this question, I'm a bit afraid it's a bad idea, whatever you're thinking about using this for.

---

[1] the nest mates feature makes this statement oversimplified (i.e. not exactly correct). But I can think of no other example that is likely to be somewhat familiar to even beginning java programmers.

Comment: The nest feature does not change what you said; there are indeed no inner classes in the JVM, as the nest feature, contrary to its name, only permits access without implementing an actual inner class relationship. That’s still the compiler’s job.

Answer (score 0):

Check the *declaring class* against the *parent class*.

```java
B.class.getMethod("e").getDeclaringClass() != A.class
```

Comment: This doesn’t work. Both methods are declared in B.

Comment: @DerekLi, so, I read your comment as well, I figured you may have misinterpreted it, so I added this answer.  You're saying it's incorrect, I don't know what to tell you.  If _e_ is _overridden_ in _B_ then the _"declaring class"_ would be _B_, and not _A_.

Comment: Read my question. The declaring class of both the overridden and original method is B because it is synthetic.

Comment: @Derek, so check the _declaring class_ of B's method, _e_.  Which, if _overridden_ would return _B_.

Comment: Quoting my answer:
```Name: e
Declaring class: Main$B
Return type: java.lang.String
Name: e
Declaring class: Main$B
Return type: java.lang.Object```

Comment: @DerekLi, At least, try the code.